# Llenar un Input a partir de un Select en Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap, .net

Estoy empezando a desarrrollar una app en Angular después de haberlo hecho con Vue. En este proceso se me presentó un inconveniente que no puedo resolverlo.
Deseo llenar un input desde un select con un el numero correlativo de un codigo de producto.
En Vue pude resolverlo pero no encunetro la forma de hacerlo en Angular.
Este es el codigo de vue que va en las propiedades computadas:

```
    selectItem: function()  {
        return this.documentos.find(item => item._id == this.documento)
    },
    codigo: function()  {
        return this.selectItem ? 
        this.selectItem.numerocorrelativo.toString().padStart(8,'EGCP000'):''
    },
```

El select y el input es el siguiente:

```
                 <b-container>
                    <b-row>
                        <b-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                            <b-form-group
                                label="Generar Codigo"
                            >
                                <b-form-select
                                    v-model="documento" 
                                    :options="documentos"
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    value-field="_id"
                                    text-field="nombre"
                                    required
                                />
                            </b-form-group> 
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                            <b-form-group 
                                label="Código Producto"
                                >
                                <b-form-input
                                    :value='codigo' 
                                    type="text" 
                                    class="form-control text-center" 
                                    readonly
                                />
                            </b-form-group>
                        </b-col>
                     </row>
                   </container>
```

Los datos vienen de una base de datos a traves de una Api construido en .NET.
El select e input en angular es el siguiente:

```
                     <div class="col-md-5">
                        <label class="visually-hidden"></label>
                        <select
                        class="form-select"
                        formControlName="idDocument"
                        >
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Genere Código</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let item of documents" [value]="item.id">
                            {{ item.nombre }}
                        </option>
                        </select>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input 
                        type="text" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        formControlName="codigo"
                        placeholder="Código"
                        :value="selectItem"
                        >
                    </div>
```

Me podrían indicar como puedo trasladar estos codigos a Angular y poder obtener el mismo resultado?
Gracias por sus comentarios y sugerencias.
Saludos